# Get-spsite giving error

Tags: 2010, powershell, site

I am getting following error for Get-SPSite with no site collection name. Any ideas on what would cause this error to showup.

> Get-SPSite : The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response
>   message does not match the content type of the binding
>   (application/soap+msbin1). If us ing a custom encoder, be sure that
>   the IsContentTypeSupported method is impleme nted properly. The first
>   1024 bytes of the response were:

> XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-st
>   rict.dtd">  
>   IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   style type="text/css"> comment symbol
>   body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;bac
>   kground:#CBE1EF;}
>   code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}
>   .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}
>   pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} ul,ol{margin:10px
>   0 10px 40px;} ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} fieldset{padding:0
>   15px 10px 15px;} .summary-container
>   fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}
>   legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}
>   legend{color:#333333;padding:4px 15px 4px 10px;margin:4px 0 8px
>   -12px;_margin-t op:0px;  border-top:1px solid #EDEDED;border-left:1px solid #EDEDED;border-right:1px so lid #969696;  border-bottom:1px
>   solid #969696;background:#E7ECF0;font-weight:bold;'. At line:1 char:11
>   + get-spsite <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:    SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite],
>   ProtocolException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite

Answer (score 0):

this error leads me towards the web.config discrepancy.

Please check the Web.config files for the Web application ( which u are trying to run the get-spsite) is correct, also check the Central admin web.config file.

You can also try to run the get0spwebapplication and see if that return any result.

Comment: Get-SpWebApplication webappURL returns the web application. When I try webapp.Sites, It gives the same error

Comment: I tried for all the web applications to get there sites, but I get above error for all webapplications

Comment: when I try ,  get-spsite http://siteUrl, I get following error  "get-spsite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:
http://siteUrl.
At line:1 char:9
+ $site = get-spsite("http://siteUrl")
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:
   SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite